# Scope of variables in Python methods with identical default parameters?

Tags: python, variables, scope, default-parameters, default-arguments

After a good bit of searching i couldn’t find any examples covering this. But i might not be using the correct terminology, since im confused about the situation, and what to even ask if that makes sense? So i feel like this is a duplicate probably.

But if you have a Python class, with two methods that have a parameter that has the same name, whats the behaviour of this?

```
class Foo():

    def __init__(self, arg1=1, arg2=2):

    def methodOne(self, amount, setting=None, extra=0):         

    def methodTwo(self, amount, setting=None):
        ...
        #What is going on with setting here? What is setting referring to?
        self.methodOne(amount, setting=setting)
```

Comment: @John1024 self is defined in the code im looking at, forgot to put that, ive updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setting` on the left can *only* be referring to a keyword argument, and the `setting` on the right can *only* be referring to a name. That's how Python's parser works.

Comment: I forgot to add self in my question, as the code im looking at has self defined, now it matches up, so maybe that changes your answer?

Comment: No. The Python parser does not change.

Comment: Ahh okay, well in that case, im still not understanding lol. What do you mean by "keyword argument" and "name"?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Comment: Okay so in `self.methodOne(amount, setting=setting)`  , the second argument is a keyword argument? And you just happen to be passing the value setting? Just as well it could be something like `self.methodOne(amount, setting='no')`? I think i understand now.

Comment: The value bound to the name "setting", yes.